# Why in many newspaper name, word "TIMES" is there?

Tags: american-english, mass-media

I was wondering that whenever I pick a newspaper I found either it is the Times of America, Times of India ,Hindustan Times and lot more  so why there is always a word times in newspaper name . Is it a culture or a style.

Answer (score 0):

When Nobel laureate [Bob Dylan](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bob_Dylan) sang

> [*The times*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Times_They_Are_a-Changin%27_(song)) they are a'changin'

he meant the current era/day, the times we live in, is becoming something new and transformed.

In the same way, a newspaper reports and comments on events of the current day as, say, opposed to an earlier time like a history. The first newspaper to use the name *Times* was in [1788](https://www.etymonline.com/word/time). Like a popular baby name, it stuck, especially as newspapers with that name became highly regarded in London and New York.